# Simulate keyboard input inside app in C++ MFC app

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, mfc

I created a dialog `MainDialog.cpp` with **2 edit controls** whose IDs are `IDC_EDITCONTROL_A` and `IDC_EDITCONTROL_B`, and have variables defined as `m_editControlA` and `m_editControlB`, respectively.

Also, I have **2 buttons** whose IDs are `IDC_MFCBUTTON_KEY_X` and `IDC_MFCBUTTON_KEY_Y`, and variables are `m_buttonKeyX` and `m_buttonKeyY`, respectively.

Below is the code in the source file

```
#include "afxdialogex.h" 

IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC(CMainDialog, CDialogEx)

CMainDialog::CMainDialog(CWnd* pParent): CDialogEx(IDD_MAIN_DIALOG, pParent)
{
}

CMainDialog::~CMainDialog()
{
}

void CMainDialog::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialogEx::DoDataExchange(pDX);

    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_EDITCONTROL_A, m_editControlA);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_EDITCONTROL_B, m_editControlB);
    DDX(Control(pDX, IDC_MFCBUTTON_KEY_X, m_buttonKeyX);
    DDX(Control(pDX, IDC_MFCBUTTON_KEY_Y, m_buttonKeyY);
}

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMainDialog, CDialogEx)
    ON_EN_CHANGE(IDC_EDITCONTROL, &CMainDialog::OnEnChangeEditA)
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_MFCBUTTON_KEY_X, &CMainDialog::OnBnClickedButtonX)
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_MFCBUTTON_KEY_Y, &CMainDialog::OnBnClickedButtonY)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

void CMainDialog::OnBnClickedButtonX()
{
    m_editControlA.SetWindowTextW(_T("X"));  // test
}

void CMainDialog::OnBnClickedButtonX()
{
    m_editControlA.SetWindowTextW(_T("Y"));  // test
}
```

I am trying to understand how I can have each button **send** their respective character (i.e. `X` or `Y` in this example) to the selected edit control *if one is selected*. Essentially, I would like to **simulate keyboard input**.

I have read the docs about [how to simulate keyboard events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/how-to-simulate-mouse-and-keyboard-events-in-code) and also the [sendMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t64sseb3.aspx) but I could not understand how to implement it since my C++ knowledge is very basic. Also, following my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44440361/create-your-own-keyboard-in-c-mfc-app) I have found that the `GetFocus` would be useful but still my main issue currently is sending the input.

Any example code or useful link could be very useful for me to learn how I can simulate a keyboard input inside an app.

Comment: The problem is that the edit controls will loose focus when the buttons are pressed. Commenters of your previous question already gave some suggestion how to solve this. Another idea: replace the buttons by static controls that have the `SS_NOTIFY` style. Statics don't receive focus by default.

Comment: Simulating keyboard events is the probably the wrong way to go here. Which problem are you _actually_ trying to resolve? This looks like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The characters are sent from the OS to the edit controls using the WM_CHAR message.

In reality it is a bit more complex than that, but you do not need to emulate the entire WM_KEYUP WM_KEYDOWN message sequence, since its end result is to generate a WM_CHAR message.

You can use CWnd::PostMessage to send characters directly to your edit controls, even when they do not have the focus.

You have probably already found the documentation for WM_CHAR here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/windows/desktop/ms646276(v=vs.85).aspx

oops.. excuse my french, ths english doc is here
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646276(v=vs.85).aspx

(just changing the fr-fr to en-us does the trick, it probably works for all other languages, neat!

- *wParam* holds the character you want to send.  Either an plain ASCII character, or one of the VK_ constants... I suggest you use the unicode version WM_CHARW, as most windows software uses unicode nowadays.  The notation for wide chars is either L'X' or _T('X'), the unicode (UTF-16) character type is wchar_t.
- *lParam* contains other keystroke details, 0 should be fine for what you want to do.

to send X, simply call

```
 m_editControlA.PostMessage(WM_CHAR, _T('X'));
```

When using the _T() notation, the character (or string) literal between the parenthesis will be automatically converted to the right character width for your app's unicode setting (you should set that to UNICODE, since that's what the OS is using, and is also the only valid encoding for Windows CE, for example, and you should get used to manipulating this type.

the _T() macros and _t* overrides for almost all C library functions operating on strings are defined in tchar.h, which is included by Visual Studio in stdafx.h.  Under MFC, you'll mostly use CString, but it's good to know where these things are.

[EDIT] When you get that running, you should start playing with WM_KEYDOWN.  You will discover that PostMessage(WM_CHAR, VK_ESCAPE) directly to your dialog does not close it, while a PostMessage(WM_KEYDOWN, VK_ESCAPE) does. And that m_editBox.PostMessage(WM_KEYDOWN, _T('X')) will send a lower key 'x' to your edit box. But that's another topic to ivestigate.

Have fun with MFC!

For your last question:

Sure, but it gets a bit more complicated, as your button will gain focus, as soon as you click on it.  You'd have to create handlers for EN_SETFOCUS for eeach of your edit boxes, and add a CWnd* data member to keep track of the last edit box that had focus.

Your EN_SETFOCUS handlers should look something like this

```
void CdlgDlg::OnEnSetfocusEdit1()
{ 
    m_pWndLastFocus = &m_edit1;
}
```

Don't forget to set the pointer to NULL in your constructor and to chjeck it's valid before calling `m_pWndLastFocus->PostMessage()` though.

Comment: I forgot to say that the windows headers will select the right version of WM_CHAR, either WM_CHARA, or WM_CHARW depending on your app's UNICODE setting.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response! Is there a way to implement your `PostMessage` approach but to not necessarily tie it to a specific edit control? In other words, I want to send the `X` when I press the X key only to that edit control which happens to be in focus.

Comment: Sure, but it gets a bit more complicated, as your button will gain focus, as soon as you click on it.  You'd have to create handlers for EN_SETFOCUS for eeach of your edit boxes, and add a CWnd* data member to keep track of the last edit box that had focus.

Comment: See answer for details.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, I will store the last focused dialog in `m_pWndLastFocus` and when the key X is pressed then I will have it fetch that `m_pWndLastFocus` so that it can write to it, correct?

Comment: Not write to it, but post it a message.  But that's the idea, yes.  Do not call delete on the pointer, since it holds an address to a member of your class, and not to a dynamic block of memory.  Correction. Not the last dialog, but the last focused edit control.

Comment: @nk-fford Here's a neat idea:  you could try to set the focus back to your edit box after the click.

Answer (score 0):

The way to synthesize input in MFC is by using the [SendInput](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310(v=vs.85).aspx) method.