# Handler for when an edit box gains focus in C++ MFC app

Tags: c++11, mfc, focus, eventhandler, setfocus

In a dialog `MainDialog.cpp` with **2 edit controls** and **2 buttons**, following this great [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44547267/6167676) I can now send a character after a button is pressed.

However, I am having problems implementing **handlers for the `EN_SETFOCUS` for my two edit boxes**.

Below is the code in the source file

```
#include "afxdialogex.h" 

IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC(CMainDialog, CDialogEx)

CMainDialog::CMainDialog(CWnd* pParent): CDialogEx(IDD_MAIN_DIALOG, pParent)
{
}

CMainDialog::~CMainDialog()
{
}

void CMainDialog::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialogEx::DoDataExchange(pDX);

    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_EDITCONTROL_A, m_editControlA);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_EDITCONTROL_B, m_editControlB);
    DDX(Control(pDX, IDC_MFCBUTTON_KEY_X, m_buttonKeyX);
    DDX(Control(pDX, IDC_MFCBUTTON_KEY_Y, m_buttonKeyY);
}

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMainDialog, CDialogEx)
    ON_EN_CHANGE(IDC_EDITCONTROL, &CMainDialog::OnEnChangeEditA)
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_MFCBUTTON_KEY_X, &CMainDialog::OnBnClickedButtonX)
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_MFCBUTTON_KEY_Y, &CMainDialog::OnBnClickedButtonY)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

void CMainDialog::OnBnClickedButtonX()
{
    m_dialog_lastFocused ->PostMessageW(WM_CHAR, _T('X'));
}

void CMainDialog::OnBnClickedButtonY()
{
    m_dialog_lastFocused ->PostMessageW(WM_CHAR, _T('Y'));
}
```

And the variable definitions in the header file:

```
CWnd* m_dialog_lastFocused = nullptr;
CEdit m_editControlA;
CEdit m_editControlB;
CMFCButton m_buttonKeyX;
CMFCButton m_buttonKeyY;
```

I tried the following

```
void CMainDialog::OnEnSetfocusEditA()
{
    m_dialog_lastFocused = &m_editControlA;
}
```

but when run and I press a button, I get a `Exception thrown: read access violation. this->m_dialog_lastFocused was nullptr. If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.`

Could someone show me what I am missing? I have basic C++ knowledge and need help on how to setup those focus handlers.

[UPDATE]
In debug I can see that the `m_dialog_lastFocused = &m_editControlA;` is **never** called when I click on that edit control before I press the button. So, it explains the nullpointer error. However, I do not understand why the `OnEnSetfocusEditA()` is not called.

Comment: You need to find out why `m_dialog_lastFocused` is `nullptr`.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Indeed. In debug I can see that the `m_dialog_lastFocused = &m_editControlA;` is never called even when I click on that edit control before I press the button. So, it explains the nullpointer error. However, I do not understand why the `OnEnSetfocusEditA()` is not called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not enough to have a handler, you also need to put it into the message map.

`OnEnSetfocusEditA` is not called because unlike `OnEnChangeEditA`, `OnEnSetfocusEditA` is not in the message map.

Modify the message map as shown here:

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMainDialog, CDialogEx)
    ON_EN_SETFOCUS(IDC_EDITCONTROL, &CMainDialog::OnEnSetfocusEditA)     // <<<<< add this
    ON_EN_CHANGE(IDC_EDITCONTROL, &CMainDialog::OnEnChangeEditA)
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_MFCBUTTON_KEY_X, &CMainDialog::OnBnClickedButtonX)
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_MFCBUTTON_KEY_Y, &CMainDialog::OnBnClickedButtonY)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

Comment: Embarrassing mistake to not inlcude it on the message map.. Thanks for pointing it out.